# why is the domain of the function in the picture >=0, why is it not just !=0

Tags: functions

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l6gk.jpg

Expression -
$$z=\sqrt[131]{\frac{x^2+y^2-2x}{2y-y^2-x^2}}$$

I do not understand why the expression under the odd root has to be greater than or equal to 0 according to Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Maybe the algorithm doesn't check for odd roots versus even roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Wolfram Alpha isn't interpreting your input as *you* intend. For Mathematica, the domain of $x$ to a non-integral power is set as the non-negative reals. This isn't correct according to many people's interpretation of that formula. To make this match what you intend use the "surd" command instead.

You have the following Wolfram Alpha input:

> domain z=((x^2+y^2-2x)/(2y-y^2-x^2)^(1/131)

I believe what you actually want is (in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain%20z%3Dsurd%28%28x%5E2%2By%5E2-2x%29%2F%282y-y%5E2-x%5E2%29%2C131%29)):

> domain z=surd((x^2+y^2-2x)/(2y-y^2-x^2),131)

Annoyingly it *looks* like both expressions are interpreted the *same* way, but this is not this case.

Comment: Thanks, I was going crazy there :)

Comment: Since Wolfram works with complex numbers by default, and uses the "prinicpal" value for powers, it turns out that an odd root of a negative number is a non-real complex number.

Comment: No problem. Several computer algebra systems do the same thing. If memory serves me right, Maple *used* to interpret $x^{1/3}$ as the 3rd real root of $x$ (so it's domain as a real function was all reals). Then a few versions ago Maple switched to interpreting it as a principal 3rd root so that when $x$ is negative it kicked out complex numbers and thus the domain changes to just non-negative reals. I can't tell you how much time I wasted before I realized, I just needed to switch to using the "surd" command (to get what I wanted)!